# While loop or dynamic execution

Tags: sql, sap-iq

I have a table: 
VIEWING_17to31_aug_server which has 393085432 rows.

I was trying to update a field by a join condition (the join condition is correct). But the query could not be executed as it exceeded query temp space.

I then tried to use while loop which did not break but has been running for ages now.

```
CREATE VARIABLE @var_period_start               datetime;
CREATE VARIABLE @var_period_end                 datetime;
CREATE VARIABLE @scanning_day                   datetime;

SET @var_period_start  = '2013-08-17';
SET @var_period_end    = '2013-08-31';
SET @scanning_day = @var_period_start;

while @scanning_day <= dateadd(dd,0,@var_period_end)
begin
    UPDATE VIEWING_17to31_aug_server
    SET A.calculated_scaling_weight = B.calculated_scaling_weight
    FROM VIEWING_17to31_aug_server AS A
    LEFT JOIN sk_prod.viq_viewing_data_scaling AS B
    ON A.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = B.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
    AND A.VIEWING_DAY = B.ADJUSTED_EVENT_START_DATE_VESPA
    AND A.VIEWING_DAY = @SCANNING_DAY
End
```

Is there any other way I can get it done faster? Will dynamic execution help?

Comment: Not sure if can fits with your application, but if you can consider each update atomic (like if the while loop fails, you want to keep the updates already done) then you could try a commit after each loop cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to increment @scanning_day within the loop, at the moment the `while` condition will never be met because `@scanning_day` remains constant as `@var_period_start`. e.g.

```
SET @scanning_day = dateadd(dd, 1, @scanning_day);
```

So your full script would become:

```
CREATE VARIABLE @var_period_start               datetime;
CREATE VARIABLE @var_period_end                 datetime;
CREATE VARIABLE @scanning_day                   datetime;

SET @var_period_start  = '2013-08-17';
SET @var_period_end    = '2013-08-31';
SET @scanning_day = @var_period_start;

while @scanning_day <= dateadd(dd,0,@var_period_end)
begin
    UPDATE VIEWING_17to31_aug_server
    SET A.calculated_scaling_weight = B.calculated_scaling_weight
    FROM VIEWING_17to31_aug_server AS A
    LEFT JOIN sk_prod.viq_viewing_data_scaling AS B
    ON A.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = B.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
    AND A.VIEWING_DAY = B.ADJUSTED_EVENT_START_DATE_VESPA
    AND A.VIEWING_DAY = @SCANNING_DAY;

    SET @scanning_day = dateadd(dd, 1, @scanning_day);
End
```